# How do I get a custom enumeration?

Tags: formatting, enumerate, text-decorations

I want to get the following "1.", "2." and "3." The color is "RoyalBlue" from the package `xcolor`, option `[dvipnames]`, and I also want a custom font for it (other than Computer Modern). Also some more vertical space if it's possible. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Should this be the numbering of an `enumerate`-environment or something else? You should at least provide the basics of a document. A MWE begins at `\documentclass` and `\end{document}`. Also do you use `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, with `enumitem`?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{classico} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., ref=\arabic*, wide=0pt, font=\color{RoyalBlue}\bfseries\classico]%
\item A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. A first example. See \ref{mylabel}.
\item $ \bigl(√{a}\bigr)² = a$.
\item $ √{a² }=\lvert a\rvert $. \label{mylabel}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I think the font in my picture is CG Omega. How can I set that font for the enumeration?

Comment: If this font doesn't have LaTeX support, you can use it with `\fontspec` and `xelatex`. Other than that, the font used for enumeration in your image looks similar to `URW-Classico` which has LaTeX support.

Answer (score 5):

With the `enumitem` package is easy... Please refer to its documentation to know how the `label`, `ref` and `font` options work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,font=\color{RoyalBlue}\usefont{T1}{utm}{b}{n}]
  \item text\label{pippo}
  \item text
  \item text
\end{enumerate}
We are referring to item \ref{pippo}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, without further info,

```
\usefont{T1}{utm}{b}{n}
```

selects the Times font in boldface.

BTW: the right option to select the `RoyalBlue` color is `dvipsnames`...

If you also want to act on the items separation use the `itemsep` option (in the following MWE I've exaggerated with `1.5em`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,font=\color{RoyalBlue}\usefont{T1}{utm}{b}{n},itemsep=1.5em]
  \item text\label{pippo}
  \item text
  \item text
\end{enumerate}
We are referring to item \ref{pippo}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want to use `CG Omega` as a font (I've downloaded roman and bold faces from https://fontzone.net/) you can use lualatex and declare, e.g.:

```
\newfontfamily{\CGOmega}{CG Omega}
```

Then you can set

```
font=\color{RoyalBlue}\CGOmega\bfseries
```

as in the following MWE (compile with lualatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newfontfamily{\CGOmega}{CG Omega}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,font=\color{RoyalBlue}\CGOmega\bfseries]
  \item text\label{pippo}
  \item text
  \item text
\end{enumerate}
We are referring to item \ref{pippo}.
\end{document}
```

[image]